# Using Android GPS as NTP refclock?

Tags: gps, clock

Is anyone aware of an existing or potential way to make an Android device run an NTP daemon which takes its reference time from the GPS hardware attached to it?

I'm talking about configuring the ntp daemon with a refclock from the list in http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/refclock.html (or an additional driver, if nothing in this list works).

I found http://time-server.android.informer.com/, which seems to enable the Android device to serve the time over the network to other devices using NTP, but it doesn't sync the system clock from the GPS time.